# React AntD Select Component: hover state

Tags: reactjs, antd

I've just started using React AntD library Select component. I noticed that when you have the select dropdown open and if you mouse leave it, the last hovered on option stays visible. Is there a way to override this behaviour? I want to remove the hovered on styling once my mouse leaves the select component...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The last hovered on option stays visible only if you've clicked that placement. If you don't clicked that placement and just hover on option, then your last hovered on option will not stay visible. So, you can't override this behaviour.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).